# Alternative to Grid Fill in Edit Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

I am sorry for such a basic question, but I have searched and I cannot find an answer.

I just want to fill this area and I believe grid fill is what I would want to keep the curvature of the model when filling in the hole. However, the selection does not satisfy the requirements of grid fill.

Is there any other operator I could use to fill the hole while keeping the curvature of the model? Or can I somehow make grid fill work?

Curved surface with hole that needs to be filled with respect to the geometry:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome. The topology is horrible. It will not work. If ever it did work, the result will look even worse. Consider modeling it again and make sure to use quad topology.

Answer (score 1):

Grid fill requires en even number of vertices. If you selected an odd number, (I can't tell from what you've shown), try to eliminate one vertex and it should work

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried increasing and decreasing a vertex but it still would not work.

Comment: Did you verify that you have an even number of vertices at the selection info on the bottom of your screen? Perform a merge by distance may clean up and simplify your selection. Or also try extrude and scale in until your have a tiny area, then f for fill it. Remesh the geometry in sculpt mode

Comment: Thank you for the help.